# Android basic layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to display in an horizontal layout some text on the left, then 2 images side by side on the right of the screen.
I can't find a way to do that...

It should look like this:

[Some text-------------------IMG1-IMG2]

Any idea ?

Comment: What is not working for you that you have tried?

Comment: That can be easily done with a `RelativeLayout`. If you don't know how to work with this layout, check out [Hello RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html). It's the most useful/flexible layout type for android in my opinion, so it's worth to learn how to use it in any case. If you got problems using it, come back and show what you tried. :)

Comment: @Aaron McIver
Using a relativeLayout all I can manage to do is
[Some text-IMG1-------------------IMG2]
or have IMG1 and IMG2 overlapping each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not want to use a relative layout? That would be ideal for this situation. If you still want to use a linear layout, try using `android:paddingRight='X dip` in the layout xml file for textview where X is an integer representing the desired padding.

Edit:
I see you have decided to go with a relative layout. The below will help you out:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/sometext"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Type here:"  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:drawable/image2"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just wanted it to work and wasn't able to do so with a RelativeLayout. Thanks a lot your solution is working !

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="This is portion of right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img2"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point for working this out:

-[Comining Multiple Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)
-[Example Layouts](http://www.android-layouts.com/)

I think one of the example layouts could be modified to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that using [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) or [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

In the first case you have to use `android:orientation="horizontal"` to stack the child Views (TextView/EditText and 2 images).

In the second case, you have to use `android:layout_<direction>` and `android:layout_alignParent_<direction>` to achieve what you want. Take time and play with it. Check out the linked tutorials for more details.